# Extracting sentence from a long string using start and end index of a word in python

Tags: python, nlp

Suppose I have a long text.

```
doc = "I was chasing a dog. I ran after it for a long time. 
... 
... 
... 
However, after running for about an hour, I caught the dog"
```

After some processing and calculation, I know that the word 'time' has start index `i` i.e `doc[i:i+4]="time"`. My question is, is there an efficient way by which I can extract the sentence from the `doc` variable that consists of the word doc?
In this case, the sentence I should get is

```
I ran after it for a long time.
```

So, using the start and index of a word in a long string, is it possible to extract the sentence that contains that word? I do not want to sentence tokenize the doc and iterate over each sentence and check if it contains the word. The main reason for it being I might have a lots of query words and hence do not want to have to iterate over each sentence every time I am querying with a word.

Comment: Use NLTK or similar to extract sentences. Then build a dictionary to map each work to a list of sentences containing that word. This preprocessing step will improve the efficiency of multi-term search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy in spaCy.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

doc = nlp(...) # use your raw text here

word = doc.char_span(i, i+4)
# word will be None if the char span isn't valid
if word is not None:
    sent = word.sent
```

This assumes that your word aligns with a spaCy token, but that seems like a reasonable assumption.

Using a regular expression to tokenize English sentences doesn't work ("I said hello to Mr. Smith." is one sentence) and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this using `regex`:

```
import regex
from typing import List


def extract_sentences(doc: str, start_index: int, word_len: int) -> List[str]:
    word = doc[start_index:start_index + word_len]
    pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=^|.)[^\s.][^.]*%s[^.]*(?=\.|$)" % word)
    return pattern.findall(doc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doc = """
    I was chasing a dog. I ran after it for a long time.
    ...
    ...
    ...
    However, after running for about an hour, I caught the dog
    """
    print(extract_sentences(doc, 48, 4))
    # ['I ran after it for a long time']
```

The idea is using the word in question to create a regular expression and extract all sentences which contain this word.

Note that I used `regex` as opposed to `re` because it allows variable look-behind lengths. That way cases where the word is in the first sentence can be dealt with properly, e.g.

```
doc = """I ran after it for a long time.
...
...
...
However, after running for about an hour, I caught the dog
"""
print(extract_sentences(doc, 26, 4))
# ['I ran after it for a long time']
```